# How to configure sandpack to show code only?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, codesandbox

I need to create documentation with code examples of components and a description of their API, I found a "Sandpack" solution that suits me, but I can’t figure out how to configure it to remove the live-code preview.

The beta.reactjs.org documentation has code examples, I need it too. And it seems to me that they use the same solution.

Can you tell me how to create a component so that code can be inserted into the child and it is displayed with syntax highlighting?

Component don't working, but it would be great if I can insert my code examples:

```
import { Sandpack } from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

function CodeBlock(props) {
  return (
    <div className="m-4 flex">
      <Sandpack
        template="react"
        code={props.children}
        options={{
          editorHeight: 100,
          readOnly: true,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export { CodeBlock };
```

Can you tell me please how to properly configure the component?

Right now I have this:

[image: Right now I have this.]

But I need this, no live-code, only preview:

[image: And I need this]

Answer (score 1):

I did not receive an answer, so I will share my configuration, which I found optimal.

**Component:**

```
//imports
import {
  SandpackCodeEditor,
  SandpackCodeViewer,
  SandpackLayout,
  SandpackProvider,
  useActiveCode,
  useSandpack,
} from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";
import prettier from "prettier";
import parserBabel from "prettier/parser-babel";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { SubHeader } from "../text/SubHeader";

//CSS
const yourTheme = {
  colors: {
    surface1: "#011627",
    surface2: "#011627",
    surface3: "#011627",
    clickable: "#6988a1",
    base: "#808080",
    disabled: "#4D4D4D",
    hover: "#c5e4fd",
    accent: "#c5e4fd",
    error: "#ffcdca",
    errorSurface: "#811e18",
  },
  syntax: {
    plain: "#d6deeb",
    comment: {
      color: "#374151",
      fontStyle: "italic",
    },
    keyword: {
      color: "#c792ea",
      fontStyle: "italic",
    },
    tag: "#93C5FD",
    punctuation: "#64748B",
    definition: "#93C5FD",
    property: {
      color: "#FBBF24",
      fontStyle: "italic",
    },
    static: "#38BDF8",
    string: "#64748B",
  },
  font: {
    body: '-apple-system,  BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"',
    mono: '"Noto Sans Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", Menlo, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Monaco, "Lucida Console", monospace',
    size: "14px",
    lineHeight: "22px",
  },
};

const Prettier = ({ codemirrorInstance }) => {
  const [prettierCode, setPrettierCode] = useState("");
  const { sandpack } = useSandpack();
  const activeCode = useActiveCode();

  const runPrettier = useCallback(() => {
    if (activeCode.code) {
      try {
        const formatted = prettier.format(activeCode.code, {
          parser: "babel",
          plugins: [parserBabel],
        });

        setPrettierCode(formatted);
      } catch {}
    }
  }, [activeCode.code]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const debounce = setTimeout(runPrettier, 100);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(debounce);
    };
  }, [runPrettier]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prettierCode) {
      const cmInstance = codemirrorInstance.current.getCodemirror();

      if (cmInstance) {
        const trans = cmInstance.state.update({
          selection: cmInstance.state.selection,
          changes: {
            from: 0,
            to: cmInstance.state.doc.length,
            insert: prettierCode,
          },
        });

        cmInstance.update([trans]);
      }

      sandpack.updateFile(sandpack.activePath, prettierCode);

      setPrettierCode(null);
    }
  }, [prettierCode]);

  return null;
};

export default function CodeBlock(props) {
  const codemirrorInstance = useRef();

  return (
    <>

      <div className="m-2 flex flex-col rounded-2xl border border-gray-200 p-0 dark:border-gray-800">
        <SandpackProvider
          theme={yourTheme}
          files={{
            "App.js": props.children,
          }}
          template="react"
        >
          <div className="flex rounded-2xl bg-gray-900 dark:bg-gray-900">
            <SandpackLayout
              style={{
                padding: "20px 20px 0px",
                border: 0,
              }}
            >
              <div className="flex min-w-[375px] max-w-[900px]">
                <SandpackCodeViewer
                  // readOnly={false}
                  // showReadOnly={false}
                  ref={codemirrorInstance}
                />
              </div>
              <Prettier codemirrorInstance={codemirrorInstance} />
            </SandpackLayout>
          </div>
        </SandpackProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Usecase:**

```
<CodeBlock>
 {`<Badge
   iconLeft={<MdLunchDining size={12} />}
   iconRight={<MdArrowForward size={12} />}
   tuning={""}
   // onClick={}
   >
   Large Badge
  </Badge>`}
</CodeBlock>
```

**How it looks:**

[image: How it looks]

This may be useful for creating your own documentation. ✌️

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the preview panel by commenting out the `<SandpackPreview />` component.

```js
import {
  SandpackProvider,
  SandpackLayout,
  SandpackPreview,
  SandpackCodeEditor,
} from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

    <SandpackProvider template="react" files={files}>
      <SandpackLayout>
        <SandpackCodeEditor
          showTabs
          showLineNumbers
          showInlineErrors
          wrapContent
        />
        {/* <SandpackPreview /> */}
      </SandpackLayout>
    </SandpackProvider>
```